# has_secure_password, wont create attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use `has_secure_password` and bcrypt (3.1.11) on my Rails app.

Here is my setup on Ubuntu:

1. I installed bcrypt with no issues and have it in my gem file
2. I have a `password_digest:string` for my users migrated in the database
3. I added `has_secure_password` to my user model

I am getting no errors, however when I go to create a user, it is asking me for a `password_digest` attribute instead of `password` and `password_confirmation`.

why is this? Shouldn't the `has_secure_password` automatically change the user to need a `password` and `password_confirmation` instead of `password_digest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you don't store the `password` and `password_confirmation`, just the `password_digest`. You never want to store plain text passwords in your db.

When you create a new user you do

```
User.create(password: 'something', password_confirmation: 'something', ..other fields..)
```

and then `has_secure_password` takes care of updating the `password_digest` in the database.

It's also a good rule to include some validations in your `User` model.

```
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create
validates :password, confirmation: true
```

Also don't forget to white list them in your controller

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
end

User.create(user_params)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that clarified it.

Answer (score -2):

You'll probably need to change the form and/or `create` template manually to contain a `password_confirmation` field. Look more closely at the has_secure_password docs maybe?